# CodeIgniter cron job with external config file

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

So i have a codeigniter 2.2 project and want to start a cron job that runs every 5 min. My question is if there is a way to export the parameters of that cron job in a codeigniter config file. So what i want is to be able to start the job and point it to the config file in which i have the time between runs (5 mins) and the name of the controller and method that should be called. Is this posible?

Answer (score 1):

Config file is just for your basic project configuration. the simplest way is to create crone job on your hosting and point URL of your controller.

Comment: I understand.. but i want a file where i can add the relative path to the contoller and the time interval so all that my server admin has to do is point the cron job to this file. Is this posible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786112/codeigniter-invoking-multiple-controllers-in-one-call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239026/codeigniter-multiple-controllers-vs-many-methods